# In calculating the radius ratio in a tetrahedral site in an FCC lattice, why do we take tetrahedral void in the middle of the body diagonal line?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, lattices

When calculating the ratio of cation / the ratio of anion in a Tetrahedral system in an FCC lattice, why do we take the void to be in the center instead of it being √3a/4 from the corner.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the value of $\sqrt(3)a/4$ from ? What do you mean by ratio of cation/ratio of anion ? Do you mean that "G" is an atom? As it stands there is a lack of clarity in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the center. The image shows 1/8 of the unit cell. It is unfortunate that they labelled the edge with $a$, conventionally used for the unit cell length. It does not matter for the result, though, because they express it in terms of ratio of radii.